# fetching json data for specific fields and storing in file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am fetching the json data like.

```
users_json = User.all.to_json
```

And storing as arry hash like.

```
arry = JSON.parse(users_json)
```

And than fetching name & email, to use for file write, right now I am doing this simple in multiple lines,

```
email = arry.map { |x| x["email"] }

name = arry.map { |x| x["name"] }
```

And pretty sure there will one line exist for do so. Please help me to improve my logic.

Comment: I don't know why you're converting it to json at all.  Why not just do `users = User.all; emails = users.collect(&:email)`

Comment: @max thanks,
actually its my task to collect data in json format and write it to file. i am new my first day on json so i did this in the way like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rails 3

```
User.select([:name, :email]).to_json
```

And for rails 4 no need of the array

```
User.select(:name, :email).to_json
```

Refer to the [APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select) for more on what ***select*** does.

Comment: awesome realy, but in the json format its also showing the id, please tell me more how can i now file write for email and name... again thanks

Comment: No. The json format does not show the id field. And google for how to write to a file. Life isn't that easy I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way can be

```
User.all.map{|x| [x.name, x.email]}.to_json
```

But really there is no point to convert into json.